# How to show data from database on datagridview combobox

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, datagridview, combobox, vb6

I write a code but i want datagridview1 values display on second datagridview2 .

```
cn.Open()
        Dim sql As String = ("SELECT [srno],[voucher_type]FROM [SchoolERP].[dbo].[manage_voucher]")
        Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "manage_voucher")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "manage_voucher"
        cn.Close()
        Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()

        cmb.HeaderText = "vaucher_mode"
        cmb.Name = "cmb"
        cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 2
        cmb.Items.Add("Paidin")
        cmb.Items.Add("Paidout")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)

        DataGridView1.Columns("srno").ReadOnly = True
```

I have two forms on form 1 in datagridview1 it shows all 3 cloumns but i want to show that data on form2 datagridview2 .[image: 1st form.it is my 1st form i want to show voucher mode on 2nd form]
[image: this is my 2nd form.on voucher mode combobox display the form1 st voucher mode value]

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which I understood, you have two forms in application and each one holds one datagridview. datagridview1 has three columns, as datagridview2 but, number 2 has comboboxes. You want to update these combobox values with number one. Is that correct?

Comment: I want display default value on datagridview2 combobox which value present on datagridview1 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

OK, in form1 (which holds datagridview1), define public static string values for each data you want to show in form2 (which holds datagridview2). assign data to these values using column3 values (for each row seperately). when you turn form2, call these values as "form1.(string name)", and assign combobox values using them. for example: (combobox.Text=form1.(string name).

Hope this helps.